# SUM query with GROUPBY

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have table like this:

```
___________________________________________________________
| Date(date)  | UserID(int)  | Enter(time)  | Leave(time) |
|_____________|______________|______________|_____________|
|'2000-01-01' | 1            | 07:00:00     | 10:00:00    |
|'2000-01-01' | 2            | 10:00:00     | 12:00:00    |
|'2000-01-02' | 1            | 07:00:00     | 12:00:00    |
|'2000-01-02' | 2            | 12:00:00     | 18:00:00    |
|'2000-01-03' | 1            | 07:00:00     | 11:00:00    |
|'2000-01-03' | 2            | 11:00:00     | 13:00:00    |
```

And I would like to have results like:

```
__________________________________________
| UserName(varchar(50)) | Summary(float) |
|_______________________|________________|
| User1                 | 12             |
| User2                 | 10             |
```

I would like to JOIN My Table1 table with Users table on Table1.UserID = Users.UserName

Could you please help me with that?

**- EDIT:**

I have tried arleady sth like:

```
SELECT Entries.UserID, CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Entries.Enter, Entries.Leave) AS float)/60 AS Hours
                            FROM Entries
                            GROUP BY Entries.UserID
```

But it does not handle UserName yet, and it do not work

**- EDIT 2:**

I have created query like:

```
SELECT   Users.UserName,
             SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Enter, Leave) as float)) / 60 AS Summary
    FROM Entries  
    RIGHT JOIN Users  ON Entries.UserID = Users.Id
    WHERE ((1=1 AND @StartDate IS NULL) OR (@StartDate is NOT NULL AND Entries.Date >= @StartDate)) AND
          ((1=1 and @EndDate is NULL) OR ( @EndDate is NOT NULL AND Entries.Date <= @EndDate))                       
    GROUP BY Users.UserName
```

But it seems to have problem with selecting all users. When i remove WHERE statement, its working. Any advice?

Comment: What problem are you having when you try to do it yourself?

Comment: No you cannot join tables using different types of data. Only possible workaround substring UserName - exctract numeric value, convert to Int and then compare with UserID

Comment: See my current status in post

Comment: Please show the structure of the `Users` table.

Comment: Why is there no UserID in your users table?

Comment: I showed only Entries table, Second table, Users has ID and UserName column

Comment: I've down-voted your question. You asked a question and were satisfied and awarded a "right answer". You then modified your question and removed the award and reallocated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the WHERE-condition to the ON-clause, otherwise the result is the same as an Inner Join.

And you should also aggregate before the join (usually performs better):

```
SELECT   Users.UserName,
         e.Summary
FROM Users as a
left join 
 (
   select UserId,
      SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Enter, Leave) as float)) / 60 AS Summary
   from Entries
   WHERE (@StartDate IS NULL OR Entries.Date >= @StartDate) 
     AND (@EndDate is NULL   OR Entries.Date <= @EndDate)                       
   group by UserId
 ) as e  
ON e.UserID = Users.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution would look something like this;

```
;WITH MyTable ([Date], UserID, Enter, Leave) AS
(
    SELECT '2000-01-01', 1, '07:00:00', '10:00:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2000-01-01', 2, '10:00:00', '12:00:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2000-01-02', 1, '07:00:00', '12:00:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2000-01-02', 2, '12:00:00', '18:00:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2000-01-03', 1, '07:00:00', '11:00:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2000-01-03', 2, '11:00:00', '13:00:00' 
)
SELECT   MT.UserID
        ,MT.Summary = SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Enter, Leave)) / 60.
        ,US.OtherUserField
FROM MyTable    MT
JOIN Users      US ON MT.UserID = US.UserID
GROUP BY UserID, US.OtherUserField
```

Regarding your EDIT 2;

```
SELECT   Users.UserName
        ,Summary    = SUM(CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Enter, Leave) as float)) / 60 
FROM Entries  
RIGHT 
JOIN Users      ON  Entries.UserID = Users.Id
                AND ((@StartDate IS NULL) OR (Entries.Date >= @StartDate)) 
                AND ((@EndDate is NULL) OR (Entries.Date <= @EndDate))                       
GROUP BY Users.UserName
```

Comment: And what if I would like to include all users, but display 0, in case when Hours was 0? This query displays only users, that has more than 0 hours

Comment: Then use an OUTER JOIN - RIGHT in this case

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is causing the `OUTER JOIN` to collapse in to an `INNER JOIN`. Will edit my post for the modification.

Comment: Since you have removed the marking of my answer as correct - please don't ask me any more questions.

Comment: That's because I have marked dnoeth as correct. In fact, both or your answers are right. Sorry, I should make another question for second edit